# How can Clementine music player put my music playlists on my Android phone?

Tags: android, clementine

I'm using Clementine music player and love it. I'm running the latest version of Ubuntu, have a Motorola Atrix, and am running PlayerPro on my phone, but will switch to another player easily. I can easily sync my songs onto my microSD card with Banshee and Clementine, but I can't sync playlists onto it with Clementine. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a perl script to do just this.  Simply save the playlist to an xspf file and run the script.  It requires a few options to work and will sync the playlist file to the phone.  If run with the 'delete' option, will remove any music from the phone not found in the playlist file.  Have a look at http://webcave.us/doku.php?id=music:start